# Limitar quantidade de caracteres por linha

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

É possível limitar a quantidade de caracteres por linha de uma `textbox` multiline usando Windows Forms C# e .Net 3.5?

Comment: Você pode fazer isso sem problemas limitando a LARGURA do textbox. Com base na largura vai caber X caracteres na linha. Edit - Coloca a propriedade AcceptsReturn="True"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criei aqui um algoritmo no KeyPress do textbox, ele limita a quantidade de caracteres em cada linha e obriga ao usuário digitar `enter` para que mude de linha:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int tamanhoMaximoPorLinha = 10; 
    int[] keysLiberadas = { (int)Keys.Enter, (int)Keys.Back };

    int posicaoAtual = textBox1.SelectionStart;
    int linhaAtual = textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(posicaoAtual);

    if (textBox1.Lines.Length == 0)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length > tamanhoMaximoPorLinha && !keysLiberadas.Contains((int)e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    else if (textBox1.Lines[linhaAtual].Length > tamanhoMaximoPorLinha && !keysLiberadas.Contains((int)e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

`e.Handled = true;` impede de digitar aquele caracter.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer uma sobrecarga (Override) em AppendText e Text em uma classe derivada.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class TextBoxExt : TextBox
    {
        new public void AppendText(string text)
        {
            if (Text.Length == MaxLength)
                return;
            base.AppendText(Text.Length + text.Length > MaxLength
                                ? text.Substring(0, (MaxLength - Text.Length))
                                : text);
        }

        public override string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Text;
            }
            set {
                base.Text = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Length > MaxLength
                                ? value.Substring(0, MaxLength)
                                : value;
            }
        }

        // Clearing top X lines with high performance
        public void ClearTopLines(int count)
        {
            if (count <= 0)
                return;
            if (!Multiline)
            {
                Clear();
                return;
            }

            var txt = Text;
            var cursor = 0;
            var brkCount = 0;

            while (brkCount < count)
            {
                int brkLength;
                var ixOf = txt.IndexOfBreak(cursor, out brkLength);
                if (ixOf < 0)
                {
                    Clear();
                    return;
                }
                cursor = ixOf + brkLength;
                brkCount++;
            }
            Text = txt.Substring(cursor);
        }
    }

    public static class StringExt
    {
        public static int IndexOfBreak(this string str, out int length)
        {
            return IndexOfBreak(str, 0, out length);
        }

        public static int IndexOfBreak(this string str, int startIndex, out int length)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                length = 0;
                return -1;
            }
            var ub = str.Length - 1;
            if (startIndex > ub)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
            for (var i = startIndex; i <= ub; i++)
            {
                int intchr = str[i];
                switch (intchr)
                {
                    case 0x0D:
                        length = i < ub && str[i + 1] == 0x0A ? 2 : 1;
                        return i;
                    case 0x0A:
                        length = 1;
                        return i;
                }
            }
            length = 0;
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que criar um evento `textchanged` e adicionar um if dá conta.

```
int jumpline = 40; //A cada 40 caracteres.
private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{    
    if(textbox99.text.Length%jumpline ==0){
        textbox99.text += "\r\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: O código possui um probleminha, ele retorna pro inicio da linha quando alcança o final. Mas me ajudou muito a solucionar o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Galera, eu sei que a pergunta já foi respondida, más como essas respostas me ajudaram a resolver meu problema, deixo aqui compartilhado mais informações.
Usei esses 2 eventos em conjuntos para melhor resolução no meu caso.
O Primeiro tem a função de:

**1.** Definir o tamanho máximo da richtextbox para 500.

**2.** Define o tamanho da linha para 75.

**3.** Se a palavra exceder o tamanho da linha, ela é transferia para linha abaixo.

**4.** Se o tamanho máximo da richtextbox for excedido é exibido uma msg.

**5.** Restringe caracteres especiais inserindo espaço na posição atual.

```
    private void rtxbAnaliseOp_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool ok = false;
        int i =  rtxbAnaliseOp.Text.Length -1;
        rtxbAnaliseOp.MaxLength = 500;
        try
        {   
            //tamanho do texto dividido pela quantidade de linhas
            if ((rtxbAnaliseOp.Text.Length / rtxbAnaliseOp.Lines.Length) >= 75)
            {
                //Nesse bloco é verificado o tamanho da palavra escrita após exceder o tamanho máximo da linha,
                //contando as casas decimais anteriores até achar o intervalo da palavra "espaço" o código insere Enter para pular de linha.
                while (ok == false)
                {
                    string x = rtxbAnaliseOp.Text.Substring(i, 1);
                    if (x == " ")
                    {
                        ok = true;
                        rtxbAnaliseOp.Text = string.Format(rtxbAnaliseOp.Text.Insert(++i, "\n"));
                        rtxbAnaliseOp.SelectionStart = rtxbAnaliseOp.Text.Length;
                    }
                    else
                        i--;
                }
            } 
            if (rtxbAnaliseOp.Text.Length >= 500)
            {                    
                // Verifica se o tamanho do texto é maior que a quantidade maxima de carateres disponíveis.
                if (rtxbAnaliseOp.Text.Length >= rtxbAnaliseOp.MaxLength)
                {
                    // Alerta o usuário que o maximo de carateres já foi escrito.
                    MessageBox.Show("Aleta! Você excedeu o limite de caracteres disponíveis");
                }                                        
            }

            //string pattern = @"[^0-9a-záéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõç\s]";
            string pattern = @"[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]";
            string replacement = "";

            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);                
            string letra = rtxbAnaliseOp.Text.Substring(i, 1);

            //Verifica existência de caracteres especiais.
            if ( Regex.IsMatch(letra, pattern ))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Aleta! Este campo não permite a inserção de Caracteres especiais");

                //Remove caracteres especiais Expressoes Regulares(Nesse caso nao aceita nada que não seja letras, numeros e espaço representado por "\s").
                rtxbAnaliseOp.Text = rgx.Replace(rtxbAnaliseOp.Text, replacement);
                rtxbAnaliseOp.SelectionStart = (rtxbAnaliseOp.Text.Length);
                //    rtxbAnaliseOp.Text = Regex.Replace(rtxbAnaliseOp.Text, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]", "");   
                //    rtxbAnaliseOp.Text = Regex.Replace(rtxbAnaliseOp.Text, pattern, replacement);
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            rtxbAnaliseOp.Text = rtxbAnaliseOp.Text + string.Format("\n");
            rtxbAnaliseOp.SelectionStart = (rtxbAnaliseOp.Text.Length);
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        { }
    }
```

---

Nesse Segundo caso é o código do nosso amigo:

> Maicon Carraro

Porém no meu caso tive que alterar a verificação do `IF` para:`if (rtxbAnaliseOp.Text.Length > tamanhoMaximoPorLinha && !keyLiberada.ToString().Contains(Convert.ToString((int)e.KeyChar)))` pois a `keyLiberada` não continha o método `String.Contains`.

```
    private void rtxbAnaliseOp_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //limita a quantidade de caracteres em cada linha e obriga ao usuário digitar enter para que mude de linha.
        int tamanhoMaximoPorLinha = 75;            
        int keyLiberada = (int)Keys.Enter;
        int posicaoAtual = rtxbAnaliseOp.SelectionStart;
        int linhaAtual = rtxbAnaliseOp.GetLineFromCharIndex(posicaoAtual);

        if (rtxbAnaliseOp.Lines.Length == 0)
        {
            if (rtxbAnaliseOp.Text.Length > tamanhoMaximoPorLinha && !keyLiberada.ToString().Contains(Convert.ToString((int)e.KeyChar)))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        else if (rtxbAnaliseOp.Lines[linhaAtual].Length > tamanhoMaximoPorLinha && !keyLiberada.ToString().Contains(Convert.ToString((int)e.KeyChar)))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Mais uma vez obrigado e espero ter ajudado.